# Cassandra bind markers or unnamed markers for list

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, datastax, cql

Please i need a help, with Accessors i can't use bind markers or unnamed markers for list.

```
CREATE TABLE user_messages (
  userid bigint,
  messages LIST<FROZEN<message>>,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);

CREATE TYPE social.message (
  messageid bigint,
  content text,
);
```

I get error message with this query below

```
@Query("update user_messages set messages = messages - [{?}] where userId = ?")
Resultset deleteMessage(List<Message> message, long userId);
```

I tried this other one below no error message but refuse to delete the message from the list.

```
@Query("update user_messages set messages = messages - ? where userId = ?")
Resultset deleteMessage(List<Message> message, long userId);
```

Comment: `@Query("update user_messages set messages = messages - [?] where userId = ?")` does it work?

Comment: @ruhul Yes it doesn't work i get error with that.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @AlexOtt this is the error message:  com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid list literal for messages: bind variables are not supported inside collection literals

Comment: Please i need help to solve this issue am new to cassandra